# InnoSetup not asking for destination folder

Tags: inno-setup

My innosetup script below does not ask for a destination folder. Why Not? As you can see, I am doing all the file copying with 7zip, since it would never fit in a setup.exe file.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Script Studio Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "EGPL GeoLibrarian"
#define MyAppVersion "2.0.1.7"
#define MyAppPublisher "Draper Laboratory"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.draper.com/"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{2A283576-02D9-453C-96B2-0F9A43F0B229}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName=F:\EGPL\GeoLibrarian
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputDir=.
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Run]
Filename: "{pf64}\\7-zip\7zG.exe"; Parameters: "x ""{src}\GL.7z"" -o""{app}\"" * -r -aoa"; Flags: runascurrentuser

[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}"
Type: files; Name: "{commondesktop}\DashBoard"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\EGPL Watson Uninstall"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\DashBoard"; Filename: "{app}\dashboard\node_modules\dist\electron.exe main.js"; WorkingDir: "{app}\dashboard"; IconFilename: "{app}\dashboard\build\configure.ico"
```

Comment: Unless I do not understand, what do you mean by *"does not ask for a destination folder"*.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl My deepest apologies for the post. I was not sure if it was better to delete it altogether, and mark it as a duplicate, or perhaps some folks would not realize the first post was a more direct answer. I now lean to deleting this post. What do you suggest?

Comment: It's ok keep it. Point of marking duplicate question is to allow others google for the problem using *your words*.